# Citing sources as a way to promote the site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

First, this isn't about the back it up rule, although it's somewhat related. Keep that in mind when thinking about the advantages and disadvantages of what I'm about to ask. Also, keep in mind that I'm not promoting spam but maybe a way to send some referral traffic to notable bloggers who post interesting stuff.

My question is this: Can we attract more experts to our site by sending referral traffic their way?  Let's use a [partial, recent answer by Oded](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/a/600/64) as an example:

> ...
>
> You need to consider your expenses and overheads - everything that you pay out in order to complete a job. This, divided by the amount of time you estimate a job to take, will give you a estimated break-even rate - a rate that will end up with no profits or liabilities (assuming your estimates are correct). This is your rock bottom rate - possibly a rate to attract customers with, but not a long term rate that you can profit from.
>
> ...

Oded didn't cite a source, but I don't think he really needed to, since he did a great job explaining why and how, two important ingredients from [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

But, Oded's great information is also backed up by a great blog post by [Christopher Penn, titled "How to set your consultant billing rate"](http://www.christopherspenn.com/2012/07/how-to-set-your-consultant-billing-rate/). Now, I've never heard of Chris Penn, and he's not a user on our site, but he is a public speaker and writes a lot of stuff that makes a lot of sense. I appreciate his comparison between the ceiling and the floor. Read his article to learn more.

So, would it be helpful to edit existing answers to enhance them with links to reputable freelancing blogs in hopes that referral traffic might make them want to check us out? Could it justify us reaching out to these bloggers and asking them to return the favor by writing an article about us or mentioning us in their next speaking event?

I didn't want to edit anyone's answer without first engaging the community, as I don't want anyone to think their answer was somehow lacking. That's definitely not the goal here. What do you think?

Comment: Interesting that you post that Blog as a reference... I was not aware of Chris, but he makes very much the same (but more eloquantly) as I did in http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/a/599/85 :)

Comment: @Andrew - That question, and your answer, is what made me do more research and what led me to that great article. :) Feel free to use it as a reference if you think it adds more value to your post.

Comment: Added to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of backing up your answers with data. I don't think that simply waiting on referral traffic to lead new users here is going to work. The "Pingback" is a common item in these kinds of situations and I think when a blog is used, posting a pingback to the answer where it was cited in the blog's comments is worthwhile and acceptable. And in the end, more effective at soliciting visitors. Pingbacks are also more useful to the blog authors as a tracking method for referrals and external links.

Comment: Does every blog platform support this?  I've seen what you're referring to in blog comments before. Do you feel like that is used by big-name bloggers or do you think they would shy away from that?

Comment: @jmort253 I've seen it on numerous platforms and wordpress, arguably one of the most ubiquitous blogging platforms, has the functionality built in. But even without built-in pingback, I've commonly seen comments that are nothing more than "Pingback " and a link. I'm not a blogger and don't frequent a lot of blogs, but from what I've read it's an accepted practice in the community at large. If we asked a well-known "professional" blogger about pingbacks, they might have more insight. From an SEO standpoint, it increases cross-links, which improves search engine ranking; so it's a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just tweeted this out to a freelancer and blogger I know who is working on an invoicing software startup here in Portland, Oregon:

> **From [@jmort253](https://twitter.com/jmort253):** @draffauf - I'm helping grow https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ . Help us with a blog post shoutout and I'll mention @scoreboardapp in our chat room.

We don't want to turn our site into a spam-bed, but a "you-scratch-our-back-we'll scratch-your-back" approach could be lucrative.